# Lighttpd single subdomain Redirect/rewrite

Tags: redirect, rewrite, lighttpd

This was originally asked on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12148620/lighttpd-single-subdomain-redirect-rewrite), but looking around here, I get a comfy feeling someone will know the answer.

I am using lighttpd and would like to have the url path for one page show as the subdomain.

For example, I have the following url: `http://test.com/blog/...`

and I would like to show it in the browser url as: `http://blog.test.com/...`

**Other detail:** The `blog.test.com` is already an existing subdomain on the same server as test.com. It's a separate Wordpress installation though. We're simply trying to get everything under one domain but keep the subdomain path.

What is the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: Are you looking to redirect users who visit `/blog` to the blog subdomain, or just to allow for the content of `/blog` to be shown when visiting the subdomain?

Comment: Yes, the latter. The content of /blog should show when someone visit the subdomain.

Comment: Can you provide the current config of the main domain and the subdomain?